# How to add jQuery slider to Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I want to add Jssor slider into my site (Wordpress)

I have the code files but don't know how to import. I have watched some tutorials and did the same steps, but didn't work.

for ex. where should I put this html file? + (and also I've 3 different .js files)

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body style="padding:0px; margin:0px; background-color:#fff;font-family:Arial, sans-serif">

            <!-- #region Jssor Slider Begin -->

            <!-- Generated by Jssor Slider Maker. -->
            <!-- This demo works with jquery library -->

            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.slider.mini.js"></script>
            <!-- use jssor.slider.debug.js instead for debug -->
            <script>
                jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

                    var jssor_1_options = {
                      $AutoPlay: true,
                      $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
                        $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,
                        $Cols: 5,
                        $Align: 200,
                        $NoDrag: true
                      }
                    };

                    var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);

                    //responsive code begin
                    //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizing
                    function ScaleSlider() {
                        var refSize = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
                        if (refSize) {
                            refSize = Math.min(refSize, 600);
                            jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
                        }
                        else {
                            window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
                        }
                    }
                    ScaleSlider();
                    $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
                    $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
                    $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
                    //responsive code end
                });
            </script>

            <style>
                /* jssor slider thumbnail navigator skin 12 css *//*.jssort12 .p            (normal).jssort12 .p:hover      (normal mouseover).jssort12 .pav          (active).jssort12 .pav:hover    (active mouseover).jssort12 .pdn          (mousedown)*/.jssort12 .w {    cursor: pointer;    position: absolute;    WIDTH: 99px;    HEIGHT: 28px;    border: 1px solid gray;    top: 0px;    left: -1px;}.jssort12 .p {    position: absolute;    width: 100px;    height: 30px;    top: 0;    left: 0;    padding: 0px;}.jssort12 .pav .w, .jssort12 .pdn .w {    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;}.jssort12 .c {    width: 100%;    height: 100%;    position: absolute;    top: 0;    left: 0;    line-height: 28px;    text-align: center;    color: #000;    font-size: 13.0px;}.jssort12 .p .c, .jssort12 .pav:hover .c {    background-color: #eee;}.jssort12 .pav .c, .jssort12 .p:hover .c {    background-color: #fff;}

            </style>


            <div id="jssor_1" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 330px; overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden; background-color: #ffffff;">
                <!-- Loading Screen -->
                <div data-u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
                    <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity: 0.7; position: absolute; display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
                    <div style="position:absolute;display:block;background:url('img/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
                </div>
                <div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default; position: relative; top: 29px; left: 0px; width: 598px; height: 299px; overflow: hidden; border: 1px solid #adadad">
                    <div style="display: none;">
                        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 598px; height: 299px;">
                            <div style="margin: 10px; overflow: hidden; color: #000;">Slide 1 content, place any html here.</div>
                        </div>
                        <div data-u="thumb">Banner Rotator</div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: none;">
                        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 598px; height: 299px;">
                            <div style="margin: 10px; overflow: hidden; color: #000;">Slide 2 content, place any html here.</div>
                        </div>
                        <div data-u="thumb">Image Gallery</div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: none;">
                        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 598px; height: 299px;">
                            <div style="margin: 10px; overflow: hidden; color: #000;">Slide 3 content, place any html here.</div>
                        </div>
                        <div data-u="thumb">Image Slider</div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: none;">
                        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 598px; height: 299px;">
                            <div style="margin: 10px; overflow: hidden; color: #000;">Slide 4 content, place any html here.</div>
                        </div>
                        <div data-u="thumb">Tab Slider</div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: none;">
                        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 598px; height: 299px;">
                            <div style="margin: 10px; overflow: hidden; color: #000;">Slide 5 content, place any html here.</div>
                        </div>
                        <div data-u="thumb">Carousel</div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!-- Thumbnail Navigator -->
                <div data-u="thumbnavigator" class="jssort12" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;width:500px;height:30px;">
                    <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin Begin -->
                    <div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default; top: 0px; left: 0px; border-left: 1px solid gray;">
                        <div data-u="prototype" class="p">
                            <div class="w">
                                <div data-u="thumbnailtemplate" class="c"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin End -->
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- #endregion Jssor Slider End -->
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Please delete your screen shoot and add codes like text format to your question...

Answer (score 0):

to import JS file into Wordpress theme you have to echo template_url before the path to the file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/Jquery.x.x.x.js"></script>
```

OR You can add it in functions.php file by using wp_enqueue_script

wp_enqueue_script ( string $handle, string $src = false, array $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, bool $in_footer = false )

```
wp_enqueue_script('JQ',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js',array(),'1.11.3',true );
```